# Mysqli object not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this piece of code:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "db");
$result = $db->query($db, "SELECT * FROM usertable");
$numrows = $db->num_rows;
print "There are $numrows people in usertable\n";
```

and get this error message:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Why does this not work?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. `$db->query($db, "SELECT * FROM usertable");` should be `$db->query("SELECT * FROM usertable");` 2. `$db->num_rows;` should be `$result->num_rows;`. Please read the documentations carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the OOP calls so you dont need to have the `$db` parameter inside the parameters

Also the num_rows call should use the MYSQL_RESULT object like this

So do

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usertable");

$numrows = $result->num_rows;
```

> Please take a look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php